# OutOfMemory - Sonar fails to analyse project source code, and it can't find issues

Tags: java, intellij-idea, sonarqube, sonarlint

I am running the plugin SonarLint, in a Java Project in IntelliJ Idea.

When I request the code analyses for the entire project, I get the following message:

**SonarLint analysis failed: Java heap space**

Here are the logs:

```
Error running SonarLint analysis
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space



java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3181)
    at java.util.Vector.grow(Vector.java:266)
    at java.util.Vector.ensureCapacityHelper(Vector.java:246)
    at java.util.Vector.addElement(Vector.java:620)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.ref.dom2dtm.DOM2DTM.addNode(DOM2DTM.java:247)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.ref.dom2dtm.DOM2DTM.nextNode(DOM2DTM.java:543)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.ref.DTMDefaultBase._nextsib(DTMDefaultBase.java:567)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.ref.DTMDefaultBase.getNextSibling(DTMDefaultBase.java:1142)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.ref.DTMDefaultBaseTraversers$ChildTraverser.next(DTMDefaultBaseTraversers.java:465)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.axes.AxesWalker.getNextNode(AxesWalker.java:337)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.axes.AxesWalker.nextNode(AxesWalker.java:365)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.axes.WalkingIterator.nextNode(WalkingIterator.java:197)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.axes.NodeSequence.nextNode(NodeSequence.java:344)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.axes.NodeSequence.runTo(NodeSequence.java:503)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.ref.DTMNodeList.<init>(DTMNodeList.java:83)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.objects.XNodeSet.nodelist(XNodeSet.java:348)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathExpressionImpl.getResultAsType(XPathExpressionImpl.java:364)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathExpressionImpl.eval(XPathExpressionImpl.java:110)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathExpressionImpl.evaluate(XPathExpressionImpl.java:191)
    at org.sonar.java.xml.XmlCheckContextImpl.evaluate(XmlCheckContextImpl.java:82)
    at org.sonar.java.xml.XmlCheckContextImpl.evaluateOnDocument(XmlCheckContextImpl.java:76)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.xml.spring.SingleConnectionFactoryCheck.scanFileWithXPathExpressions(SingleConnectionFactoryCheck.java:45)
    at org.sonar.java.xml.XPathXmlCheck.scanFile(XPathXmlCheck.java:36)
    at org.sonar.java.xml.XmlAnalyzer.simpleScanAsXmlFile(XmlAnalyzer.java:107)
    at org.sonar.java.xml.XmlAnalyzer.simpleScan(XmlAnalyzer.java:97)
    at org.sonar.java.xml.XmlAnalyzer.scan(XmlAnalyzer.java:81)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.XmlFileSensor.execute(XmlFileSensor.java:55)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.analyzer.sensor.NewSensorsExecutor.executeSensor(NewSensorsExecutor.java:72)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.analyzer.sensor.NewSensorsExecutor.execute(NewSensorsExecutor.java:63)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.analyzer.sensor.PhaseExecutor.execute(PhaseExecutor.java:36)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.analysis.AnalysisContainer.doAfterStart(AnalysisContainer.java:142)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:125)
```

**How to increase the memory?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse:  `Run` --> `Run Configurations` --> then select the project under `maven build` --> then select the tab "JRE" --> then enter `-Xmx1024m`.

`Run` --> `Run Configurations` --> select the `"JRE"` tab --> then enter `-Xmx1024m`

I would suggest you to use [profiler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/profiler.html) to check how much memory you need so that you dont allot too much.

I missed IntelliJ Idea:

You can get info [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/increasing-memory-heap.html)

Please make sure that you increased heap in a correct place. You need to click 'Properties' button in IDEA's Ant tool window and edit 'Maximum heap size (Mb)' field there.

Comment: Did you see that I am asking about SonarLint IntelliJ plug-in?

Comment: its using 'Java heap space'

Comment: It is obvious that it is using heap space. But the way you provided to increase does not work.
"
Run --> Run Configurations --> select the "JRE"  "

There is no path in IntelliJ to this. And I run SonarLint, as an IntelliJ plugin, not as a task in my build process.